# flyway unable to init or migrate after a clean

Tags: flyway

I've just performed a clean operation, i've added a new schema one the prop file then ran clean again to remove that schema from db then when i tried to do a migrate it doesnt allow me  i get the following:

```
Creating Metadata table: [xx].[schema_version]
Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE [xx].[schema_version] (
    [version_rank] INT NOT NULL,
    [installed_rank] INT NOT NULL,
    [version] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [description] NVARCHAR(200),
    [type] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [script] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    [checksum] INT,
    [installed_by] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [installed_on] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [execution_time] INT NOT NULL,
    [success] BIT NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX [schema_version_vr_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([version_rank]);
CREATE INDEX [schema_version_ir_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([installed_rank]);
CREATE INDEX [schema_version_s_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([success]);
```

Also when i tried to initialize it sing init i get the following:

```
 Creating Metadata table: [xx].[schema_version]
    Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE [xx].[schema_version] (
        [version_rank] INT NOT NULL,
        [installed_rank] INT NOT NULL,
        [version] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        [description] NVARCHAR(200),
        [type] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        [script] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
        [checksum] INT,
        [installed_by] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        [installed_on] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
        [execution_time] INT NOT NULL,
        [success] BIT NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE INDEX [schema_version_vr_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([version_rank]);
    CREATE INDEX [schema_version_ir_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([installed_rank]);
    CREATE INDEX [schema_version_s_idx] ON [xx].[schema_version] ([success]);

ERROR: Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute() at line 91
ERROR: Caused by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The specified schema name "xx" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
ERROR: Occured in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError() at line 197
```

Please not that I've dropped all the objects and I can confirm they do not exist on my DB instance.

How can I overcome this? I am concerned when using the tool in dev and prod environment we can't just delete the db instance and start again. at this point I cant use the tool to do the migration and i dont want to delete the db to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway's schema creation is currently an all or nothing deal. Either all schemas are missing and then all will be created or at least one schema is present and then none will be created.

For you this means that you must either create xx yourself or drop the other schemas first.

Comment: Is this still the case with latest version 4.2.0?